# Why MMU must be built in hardware

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I know the basic about the memory management unit, but I want know why it must be built in the hardware.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867304/virtual-memory-without-hardware-support   I suppose you could do this without hardware support (in code by the operating system), but it would be terribly slow because every memory access would then need a system call.

Comment: For the same reason that  graphics operations are done in specialized hardware - performance. Doing it in code would make it too slow to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The MMU does not necessarily have to be build entirely in hardware. They can (and are) be implemented using microcode.